# Writing Python functions

Tags: python, function, optimization

This code executes well, but I don't think this the best way to do it.

```py
def bank_account(Name, number, username, passwrod):
    Output = Name, number, username, passwrod
    return Output

new_name = input ("Please Enter Your Name: ")
new_number = input ("What's your number please: ")
new_username = input ("Enter your UserName: ")
new_passwrod = input ("(Integers Only!) Enter your Passwrod Sir: ")

print("Your Data has been saved!",  bank_account(new_name, new_number, new_username, new_passwrod))
```

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: It’s difficult to tell what you are after here. The code does little more than input data and print it out again. Are you after something else?

Comment: As @quamrana noted, your function isn't doing anything except returning a tuple of the given arguments. This is functionally the same as `bank_account = (new_name, new_number, new_username, new_passwrod)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments suggest, what you're trying to do is unclear!

Maybe something the `bank_account` function can do is validate the input?
For example you specify that the `password` must be numeric. For arguments sake let's say the same is true for the `number`. Also just assume that the `name` must only consist only of alphabetic letters.

```
def bank_account(name, number, username, password):
    if not name.isalpha():
        print('Your name must only contain letters!')
        return 'Invalid'
    try:
        number = int(number)
        password = int(password)
    except ValueError:
        print('Your number and password must be numeric!')
        return 'Invalid'
    return name, number, username, password


new_name = input("(alphas) Please Enter Your Name: ")
new_number = input("(ints) What's your number please: ")
new_username = input("Enter your UserName: ")
new_password = input("(ints) Enter your Password: ")

print("Your details:", bank_account(new_name,
                                    new_number,
                                    new_username,
                                    new_password))
```

Hope this gives you an idea of something you can do with your bank_account function!